# Why is my below flipCoin1 function always returning false, while flipCoin2 works properly returning true and false randomly?

Tags: javascript

```
function flipCoin1() {
  console.log("flipCoin", Math.random < 0.5);
}
flipCoin1();
// OP : always returns false

function flipCoin2() {
  let a = Math.random();
  console.log("flipCoin1", a < 0.5);
}
flipCoin2();
// OP : returns true and false randomly
```

flipCoin1 function always returns false, while flipCoin2 works properly returning true and false randomly?

Comment: Typo `Math.random` -> `Math.random()`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the function itself in the first function. You need to call it.

```
function flipCoin1() {
  console.log("flipCoin", Math.random() < 0.5);
}
```